# Why I failed to build ruby into OpenBSD-5.2 on QEMU?

Tags: ruby, qemu, rbenv, openbsd

I want to use ruby-2.0.0-p247 in OpenBSD-5.2 that works on QEMU.

- dmesg of my OpenBSD-box is here -> http://pastie.org/8111667

And, I want to use rbenv and ruby-install for installing ruby.

Okay, I installed rbenv and ruby-install into my OpenBSD-box.
But, I've seen an error when building ruby.

```
# rbenv install ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

- Response for this command is here -> http://paste.ubuntu.com/5845506/

Why I've seen it? Tell me please.

Best regards.

::: Postsctipt :::

- I don't want use Vagrant because some cause.

Comment: rbenv might not be compatible with OpenBSD. Try rvm instead? Or perhaps build ruby by hand. It's not too complicated to install it manually.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about compatibility with OpenBSD. I'll try rvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your link it seems that the problem is that rbenv expects GNU sed but on openbsd the default BSD sed implementation conforms to a superset of POSIX.2 and it doesn't use any fancy regular expressions like GNU sed.

But in any case you can edit rbenv to call gsed (or alias it?). you can install that through ports or pkgs . The port resides in /usr/ports/textproc/gsed .
to understand the differences check the package info listing:

> GNU sed isn't really a true text editor or text processor. Instead, it
>   is used to filter text, i.e., it takes text input and performs some
>   operation (or set of operations) on it and outputs the modified text.
>   Sed is typically used for extracting part of a file using pattern
>   matching or substituting multiple occurrences of a string within a file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Casper and ramrunner.

Just I tried to build ruby by hand, but I see same result.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && make install > /tmp/build.log 2>&1
```

- response -> http://pastie.org/8119520

I'll try to install gsed, and alias it.